# I have a list of terminal commands I don't even know where to start "compiling"

Tags: macos, terminal, automation, applescript, osx-elcapitan

I often receive folders full of different file types. I have a "cheatsheet" I use to locate same file types and move to various external drives (attached) and then delete off my SSD.

I was wondering if it's possible to create an applescript or something similar to run maybe an action on the main folder and have it do this for me (recursively) maintaining folder hierarchy.

[Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Iuj8gMfe2GQ1dVNnYtMFFWQXc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How are you identifying the files, by file extension?

Comment: Well i've come up with this, these particular extensions are for one program:

Comment: I will attach a .txt to the , cause I'm really not sure how this guy works lol.

Comment: [link]https://www.evernote.com/shard/s733/sh/17798a32-7ee3-4471-8fc0-c8ebe6c35bf0/eccc11efb69c79a17cbb0cc4e2d6dbcb